# Facebook fan count on a given date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I am not a programmer and I have literally no idea about the Facebook API. However, I need to collect some data from six different Facebook pages for my thesis, and I'm not the admin of them.

I've managed to get all the statuses, likes, comments of the 6 Facebook pages from a year using:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select permalink,like_info,comment_info,share_info,created_time from stream where source_id={fan-page-ID} and created_time < {time-in-Unix-timestamp} and actor_id={fan-page-ID} ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 20000&access_token ={your-access-token}
```

Now I need to get the number of fans the six pages had during the year (the variation). I would like to know how many fans the page had on a certain date. I've found this:

```
http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=xml&query=select fan_count,name from page where page_id={fan-page-ID}
```

And it works but it gives me the number of fans for today, not a certain date that I want. Any idea how can I achieve that? It would be amazing if I could get an XML so I can open it in excel for further analysis.

Comment: is that a very old app? FQL is deprecated since a very long time and will stop working for all apps very soon (August 7, 2016)

Comment: No idea, that's what I found and it has worked perfect for what I needed...

Comment: Hi, no idea at all? :(